# Extract domain with subdomain in side class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I have an `ASP.NET 3.5 Web application with C# 2008`.

What I need to do is, I want to extract full domain name in side a class method from Current URL.

For example :

I do have Current URL like :

```
http://subdomain.domain.com/pagename.aspx
```

OR

```
https://subdomain.domain.com/pagename.aspx?param=value&param2=value2
```

Then the `result` should be like,

```
http://subdomain.domain.com
```

OR

```
https://subdomain.domain.com
```

Comment: @Jonesy: No.  There are too many TLDs to put in a regex.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for the `Uri` class:

```
new Uri(str).GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Uri` and query the [`Host`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.host.aspx) property:

```
var uri = new Uri(str);
var host = uri.Host;
```

(Later)

I just realized that you want the scheme *and* the domain. In that case, @SLaks answer is the one you want. You could do it by combining the `uri.Scheme` and `uri.Host`, but that can get messy for things like `mailto` urls, etc.